# sql server 2008 stored procedure optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, its really simple, just one select statement, however the where clause changes based on the parameters.

I am using if else statement and wrote out the select 4 times, is there a better way to simplify this stored procedure?

```
    IF @Status > 0 
        BEGIN
            IF @Group = ''
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  *
                    FROM    ( SELECT    tbl.* ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY tbl.NDB_No ) rownum
                              FROM      dbo.FoodAbbrev AS tbl
                              WHERE     Status = @Status
                            ) seq
                    WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
                    ORDER BY seq.rownum
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  *
                    FROM    ( SELECT    tbl.* ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY tbl.NDB_No ) rownum
                              FROM      dbo.FoodAbbrev AS tbl
                              WHERE     Status = @Status
                                        AND GroupCd = @Group
                            ) seq
                    WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
                    ORDER BY seq.rownum

                END
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            IF @Group = ''
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  *
                    FROM    ( SELECT    tbl.* ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY tbl.NDB_No ) rownum
                              FROM      dbo.FoodAbbrev AS tbl
                            ) seq
                    WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
                    ORDER BY seq.rownum
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  *
                    FROM    ( SELECT    tbl.* ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY tbl.NDB_No ) rownum
                              FROM      dbo.FoodAbbrev AS tbl
                              WHERE     GroupCd = @Group
                            ) seq
                    WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
                    ORDER BY seq.rownum

                END
        END
END
```

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's excellent [Dynamic Search Conditions in SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) would usually be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all these `IF` statements with the following one `SELECT` statments with optional parameters:

```
   SELECT  *
   FROM    ( SELECT    tbl.* ,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY tbl.NDB_No ) rownum
             FROM      dbo.FoodAbbrev AS tbl
             WHERE     1 = 1
             AND (@Group IS NULL OR GroupCd = @Group)
             AND (@Status IS NULL OR Status = @Status)
   ) seq
   WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
   ORDER BY seq.rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                SELECT  *
                FROM    ( SELECT    tbl.* ,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY tbl.NDB_No ) rownum
                          FROM      dbo.FoodAbbrev AS tbl
                          WHERE     ISNULL(Status,0) = CASE WHEN @Status > 0 THEN @Status ELSE ISNULL(Status,0) END
                          AND       ISNULL(GroupCd, '') = CASE WHEN @Group = '' THEN ISNULL(GroupCd, '') ELSE @Group END
                        ) seq
                WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
                ORDER BY seq.rownum
```